# pod 'Firebase' not installing

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to install 'Firebase' pod using:

pod 'Firebase'

But when I run 'pod install' command I get the following error:

```
Alis-MacBook-Pro:Trydan-E-iOS aliehsan$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.8.2)
Using ESPullToRefresh (2.7)
Installing Firebase (6.2.0)

[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /Users/aliehsan/anaconda3/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/8n/38bpdxkn4cq7s75vc0z9_5km0000gn/T/d20190612-93280-qctgon/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/c7dba84b10c22663/Firebase-6.2.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/aliehsan/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found


[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `12.2` on target `Trydan-E-iOS` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong? Please guide. JazakAllah.

Comment: The last line is pretty self-explanatory: `Automatically assigning platform 'ios' with version '12.2' on target 'Trydan-E-iOS' because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Firebase or CocoaPods error. Notice how your computer is trying to run `curl` from your `anaconda3` folder instead of `usr/bin`. [You probably just need to change the `PATH` order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502480).